# navigator.mediaDevices is undefined when page is served by WampServer

Tags: javascript, firefox, wampserver, navigator, mediadevices

On Firefox 70.0.1, when I open a page served by WampServer 3.1.9 and test `navigator.mediaDevices`, I get `undefined`.

If I open the same page via its `file:///` URL, `navigator.mediaDevices` is a valid object.

How can the way the page is accessed affect the `navigator` object?

I just mention that I created a new virtual host on WampServer to host the page.